# How to prove Tangent passes only through one point in a function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to solve this problem but not been successful.

A) Criticize the following definition:

> The tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$
>   at $P$ is the line which touches the curve only at $P$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What thoughts do you have?

Comment: I wonder what teachers, who ask a question like this, have in mind. Do they want students to show that this definition is not equivalent to the standard definition, or to they want students to explain how the standard definition is a more useful notion than this notion? If the former, then why not say what you mean, and if the latter, I don't see how someone just beginning to study calculus could be expected to answer it.

Comment: Note that the Question's title does not agree with the quoted exercise.  The exercise is to *criticize* the definition, not to prove that it is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example where this does not happen. The curve is $y=x^3$.

[image: Graph]

The tangent intersects the curve at some other point.

Comment: Or $y = \sin x$, where this happens infinitely many times.

Answer (score 2):

Helpful Remark: What does the tangent to a line at a point look like?